# Capybara choose radio button

Tags: testing, capybara

I have a set of radio buttons that reveal more options on a page when they are clicked. Here is the set of radio buttons...

```
<div class="field">
Single
<input id="selection_single" type="radio" value="single" name="selection" checked="checked">
Repeating Dates
<input id="selection_repeating" type="radio" value="repeating" name="selection">
</div>
```

I am trying to click the 2nd button w/id selection_repeating. In my spec file I have     choose("selection_repeating"), but am getting an error when running the script saying       Unable to find radio button "selection_repeating". Any ideas?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having a similar error.

Comment: My issue ended up being unrelated to the radio button selection. Double check your tests and be sure its the radio button that is failing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It turns out I had overlooked creating the record from which the radio button was created. Gripes :)